# Scraping quarantined subreddits

Tags: python, web-scraping, reddit, praw

I'm working on a misinformation project and I want to scrape a couple of quarantines subreddits (r/russsia specifically).
When I follow the guidelines posted on the [praw docs](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/subredditquarantine.html) I get a `prawcore.exceptions.Forbidden: received 403 HTTP response` error.

I saw a couple of solutions from 3+ years ago about manually adding the subreddit on the browser and using `quarn.opt_in()` but no luck. Below is a code snippit:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Comment Extraction (by /u/guy_asking_on_stackoverflow)',
                     client_id=sec.reddit_client_id, client_secret=sec.reddit_client_secret)

subred = reddit.subreddit(subreddit)
subred.quaran.opt_in() # error happens here

# for post in subred.top(limit=10): ERROR HAPPENS BEFORE, KEPT FOR POST HISTORY
#     pass  # error happens here
```

`subred` is of type, `praw.models.reddit.subreddit.Subreddit` but it will not return submissions.

Any ideas for a solution?

full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/envs/work3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3361, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-9de81e112c74>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    for post in subred.top(limit=10):
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/envs/work3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 63, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/envs/work3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 73, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/envs/work3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 595, in get
    return self._objectify_request(method="GET", params=params, path=path)
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/envs/work3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 696, in _objectify_request
    self.request(
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/envs/work3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 885, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/envs/work3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 330, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/envs/work3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 266, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
prawcore.exceptions.Forbidden: received 403 HTTP response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape quarantined subreddits your client cannot be read only.

You can make your client fully authorized by also providing the account username and password.

```py
reddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Comment Extraction (by /u/guy_asking_on_stackoverflow)',
                     client_id=sec.reddit_client_id, client_secret=sec.reddit_client_secret,
                     password=sec.reddit_password, username=sec.reddit_username)
```

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/authentication.html#password-flow